# MS Sql Query to Select only Char Part

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a Sql Database Column called StateNames From Customer Table

StateCode COLUMN have Data Like

```
27 MAHARASHTRA    
23 BIHAR    
234 SHILONG
```

etc..

I have to select only string Part.. I.e `MAHARASHTRA` or `BIHAR`..

Please Suggest

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep char(1), @s varchar(5120))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
  SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
  FROM Pieces
  WHERE stop > 0
)
SELECT pn AS [Index],
  SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 5120 END) AS [Value]
FROM Pieces
)
```

Then

```
SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.Split(' ', YourColumnName) WHERE [Index] = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If the delimiter is a particular character like space, then use `CHARINDEX`.

```
DECLARE @StateCode VARCHAR(100) = '234 SHILONG'

SELECT
    Original = @StateCode,
    PositionOfSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @StateCode),
    State = CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', @StateCode) > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(
                @StateCode, 
                CHARINDEX(' ', @StateCode) + 1,
                100)
        ELSE
            @StateCode END
```